# Error con Code::Blocks. "Error adding symbols: file format not recognized collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: compilar, codeblocks, instalacion

Este error me lleva apareciendo desde que instalé Code::Blocks por primera vez. He intentado re-instalar el programa varias veces, y demás pero todo sin éxito. Sé que no tiene que ver con el código por que cuando el código no está bien escrito o falta algo, en vez de salir el error del titulo, sale error de compilación, lo cual es lo normal y lo que debería ser. Entiendo que el error es que no reconoce el formato, pero no sé como solucionarlo. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. El error es el siguiente:

```
"-------------- Build: Debug in Práctica 1 ED - Colas (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -L"C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -o "bin\Debug\Práctica 1 ED - Colas.exe" obj\Debug\main.o   
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib/libmingw32.a: error adding symbols: file format not recognized  
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))"
```

Comment: Por favor comparte el error como texto no como imagen. Ya que como imagen es muy dificil hacer uso de la informacion de los errores, y por ende nos dificulta ayudarte

Comment: De acuerdo. En principio ya está. Muchas gracias por el consejo, es que es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow

Comment: Hola, gracias por corregirlo. Te recomiendo entonces que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask] para guiarte en el sitio. Saludos